# How to set custom theme for custom modules?

Tags: module, themes, sugarcrm

I'm new in Sugar and i have created my custom modules. i wonder how to set custom theme for my custom modules. It means that theme is only applied to my modules. I'm using SugarCE-6.5.9. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are fine with inline styling it is an option. Else you can use javscript to load your css externally like, $(document).ready(function() {
    YAHOO.util.Get.css('<PATH_TO_CSS>');
});

Comment: Thank you davidboris, but i don't want to use sugar default theme, i want to use my theme only for my custom module. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: In your custom module, you will have Sugar modules tab at top or not?

Comment: I have made a custom theme, Sugar modules tab won't appears at top, i designed different header and footer. Problem is when i set default theme, it was applied for all modules.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following folder structure: /custom/themes/custom.less. In the custom.less file, you can add your own css styles. Note that this works for SugarCRM 7. I've not tested this on SugarCRM 6.